# JavaScript run-time error : 'kendo' is undefined

Tags: javascript, vb.net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I suddenly get an error(JavaScript run-time error : 'kendo' is undefined).
I use 'kendo-ui' well until yesterday.
When I open my project today, I suddenly get the error.
the project was worked well yesterday.
I didn't change any code. I don't know why this error suddenly happens.

**BundleConfig.vb**

```
bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
               "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"))

bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"))

bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"))

bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/kendo").Include(
           "~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.all.min.js",
           "~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.timezones.min.js",
           "~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"))

bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"))

bundles.Add(New StyleBundle("~/Content/kendo/css").Include(
                "~/Content/kendo/kendo.common.min.css",
                "~/Content/kendo/kendo.default.min.css"))

BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = True
bundles.IgnoreList.Clear()
```

**Layout.vbhtml**

```
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.kendo.min.css" />

    <script src="js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")        
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/kendo")

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/kendo/css")        

</head>
<body>

    @RenderBody()

</body>
```

**Web.config**

```
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Comment: Clean and rebuild the application... Also try closing the Visual studio and reopening it... Also try system restart

Comment: @Reddy, I just followed ur comment, but it doesn't solve this error. When I build this application, a program that blocks virus feels 'kendo.js' is in danger...But another program that use same Kendo-ui is built well. hmm...

Comment: hmmm strange. write a sample app to use kendo and see if it works..

Comment: Hi, check js files in browser, if it is loaded correctly. I see on your example, that you link kendo and jquery twice. But both from different locations. Check the correct one, if it cause problem or not. It can be caused if you are using kendo components but kendo is not loaded correctly - in this situation .. kendo is not defined...

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have this in your layout file?

```
<script src="js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")        
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/kendo")
```

Shouldn't it be just like this, using the bundles?

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")        
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/kendo")
```

Otherwise `kendo.all.min.js` is in the Layout and the Bundle.  It should be one or the other.